# Poorly performing query needs rewriting

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a piece of code that's performing badly, and need to rewite it to introduce a proper where clause before starting the .ToList however, that's where I'm getting stuck.

Currently the code looks lke this (roughly, I've taken some of the search criteria out to make it easier to display)

```
var Widgets = from b in _caspEntities.Widgets.Include("WidgetRegionLogs")
                    .Include("WidgetStatusLogs").Include("WidgetVoltageTests")
                        select b;

IEnumerable<Widget> results = Widgets.ToList();
if (comboBoxRegion.SelectedValue.ToString() != "0")
{
    results = from b in results
              where b.CurrentRegionLog != null && b.CurrentRegionLog.RegionId == int.Parse(comboBoxRegion.SelectedValue.ToString())
              select b;
}

if (comboBoxStatus.SelectedValue != null)
{
    results = from b in results
              where b.CurrentStatusLog != null && b.CurrentStatusLog.StatusId == comboBoxStatus.SelectedValue.ToString()
              select b;
}

if (txtCode.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
{
    results = from b in results
              where b.CodeNumber == txtCode.Text.Trim()
              select b;
}

dataGridViewWidget.DataSource = results.ToList();
```

I can write the SQL easily enough, essentially the model is simple, I have a Widget it has a RegionLog and a StatusLog, both of which store a history. The current region and status are retrieved from this by grouping by WidgetID and selecting the most recent Date Updated (and then going off to Region and Status tables to get the actual value).

So, I need to translate this into LINQ, but to be honest I don't have a clue but am ken and willing to learn. In my head, I think I need to add some better where clauses, and then do the Widget.toList after I have applied the where clauses. I'm struggling with the `CurrentRegionLog` and `CurrentStatusLog` concepts as they are not populated until I run the `IEnumerable`.

If anyone can give some pointers, I'd be grateful, 
Thanks

Edit - Added

```
    public BatteryRegionLog CurrentRegionLog
    {
        get { return _currentRegionLog; }
    }

    private BatteryRegionLog _currentRegionLog
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.BatteryRegionLogs.Count > 0)
            {
                BatteryRegionLog log = this.BatteryRegionLogs.OrderByDescending(item =>    item.LastModifiedDate).First();
                return log;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compose the query like this:

```
    if (comboBoxRegion.SelectedValue.ToString() != "0")
    {
        var id = int.Parse(comboBoxRegion.SelectedValue.ToString()
        Widgets = from b in Widgets
                  let currentRegionLog = 
                        b.BatteryRegionLogs
                         .OrderByDescending(item => item.LastModifiedDate)
                         .FirstOrDefault()
                  where currentRegionLog.RegionId == id)
                  select b;
    }
    ... // Same for the other criteria.

    dataGridViewWidget.DataSource = Widgets.ToList();
```

The whole query is not executed before you do `ToList()`. As everything is translated to SQL you don't need the null check `b.CurrentRegionLog != null`. SQL will evaluate `b.CurrentRegionLog.RegionId == id` just fine when there is no `CurrentRegionLog`.

**Edit**

Since `CurrentRegionLog` is a calculated property of your `Widget` class it cannot be translated into SQL. I made an effort to incorporate the code of calculated property into the query in a way that only the basic navigation property is used, so EF can translate it to SQL again.

Comment: Thanks Gert, I have tried this by am getting the following error.. The specified type member 'CurrentRegionLog' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported. I'd guess that I need to set this somewhere, but I'm clutching at straws a bit :-(

Comment: What is the code behind `CurrentRegionLog`? It should be a navigation property.

Comment: private BatteryRegionLog _currentRegionLog
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.BatteryRegionLogs.Count > 0)
                {
                    BatteryRegionLog log = this.BatteryRegionLogs.OrderByDescending(item => item.LastModifiedDate).First();
                    return log;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

Comment: In my simple "old style" programmer head, I need to call this just before I do the query above, is that correct?

Comment: Such properties can not be translated into SQL, which eliminates query composition as I proposed. You should find a way to use only pure navigation properties, otherwise it can only be done as in your original code.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help Gert. So, woudl this work (in pseudo code).... Var Region = get the current locations for all widgets   Var Status = get the current status for all widgets and then use these in the .include on the Widget query?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Include the code for `CurrentRegionLog`  (not `_currentRegionLog`), `CurrentStatusLog` and `CodeNumber` in your question. Maybe it show a way to improve your query.

Answer (score 0):

try remove this line:

```
IEnumerable<Widget> results = Widgets.ToList();
```

and just use the `Widgets` variable you get in at the top

The `.ToList()` goes to the database and materialiaze all the data into entities.

if you don't call the `.ToList()` the query is still "open" for a `where` clause

Comment: Thanks Jens, I'm sure to sound a bit dumb, but won't that lost the functionality of getting the data into my data grid?

Comment: @MikeH There are no dum questions :) I don't belive it will. At the buttom of you code example you do infact call the `.ToList()` and this will fire the complete query (including the where cluase) to the database.

Comment: Thanks Jens, I really need to get on a C# course! I tried this and get the following error "The specified type member 'CurrentRegionLog' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported"

Comment: I think this is because the CurrentRegionLog is derived rather than being stored on the Widget DB table

Comment: Aah i see. So `CurrentRegionLog` does not map to a database table column. Then i would suggest you do like Gert Arnold has shown. Thats is: replacing the where clause. Just remember to also implement me answer - or there is no proformance benefit.